# Image base64 stored in Json file doesn't work with FileReader and JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, base64, filereader

I want to read and load a json file with some images in base64 using FileReader, but I have an error like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token G in JSON at position 465971
```

This is my code to call the file:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( 
    urlSettingJson,                                  // File Path
    function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(file,'UTF-8');
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                var thisResult=this.result;
                window.localStorage["appSetting"]=thisResult;
                appSetting=JSON.parse(thisResult);   // Error Point
                setMenuApp(appSetting.menu);
                setFuncApp(appSetting.func);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Json file is good because if delete two images the code work properly... could be a file size problem?
Can I save multiple base64 image in json file?

Here my code work ( http://jsfiddle.net/udqa90sr ), but in this case json is in a variable.

Thanks for support

Comment: Let's see the JSON please.

Comment: how to reproduce error in the fiddle?

Comment: it's very big and exceed stackoverflow limit on text. the code is the same that written in jsfiddle

Comment: I don't know if there is a system to reproduce the error because we need to load a file